# Best whey protein with no GMO

Tags: muscle, protein, whey

I'm interested in buying a protein powder for first time in my life. I've been reading a lot, learning about what differences between protein powders are, and 2 hours ago I made up my mind and chose "Dymatize iso 100". Nevertheless, before buying it I read a bit more about it and realized that it's GMO ingredients (thing that I find extremely bad for such a high price), and also doesn't any certification (CoA or FDA). This protein powder is an auto-gift to me this Christmas, that's why I don't mind the price (I'm wiling to pay at most 100 USD since I'm aware that you have to pay for quality), but I don't want to buy something that may be harmful for me in the future.

I've been working out for a one year long, I lost weight and got the ideal BMI and now I want to get into a gain/build muscle stage. I wanted to buy "Dymatize iso 100" because it is hydrolyzed, so that I was going to get a high protein/serving+BCAA powder with low carbs/sodium.

What do you recommend me? I am open mind to new ideas :)

(PS. I live in Czech Republic, so it'd be nice if you can recommend me something easy to find abroad)
Thanks and marry xmas!!!

Comment: well, I 'd recommend to read this first https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/is-genetically-modified-food-safe-to-consume (well, basically eveything is GMO nowadays and it's fine)

Comment: second, all of this top label products (ON, BSN, Universal, Dymatize) are almost the same and safe, it's just protein like you can get from milk-made products but concentrated that's it, so

Comment: Thank you, I've found quite suitable the answer that's given in that question

Comment: You can check this whey. It is grass fed. https://orgainic.com/produkt/bio-whey-protein/

Comment: You are overthinking. It's just some protein. It's basically like drinking milk minus the sugar. No need to research and worry about it so much